# How to load multiple field in an autocomplete text view

Tags: android, search, arraylist, autocomplete, textview

I want to add a search option in my Android app. I've added an autocomplete `textView` in my layout to do so and load an `ArrayList<String`> in it. But my `ArrayList` store only one item in a row. I need to load multiple items (such as `ImageView`, `TextView` as Title, `TextView` as Sub Title).

I want to something like

[image]

Comment: you should search for AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter.

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: @Mistalis : I am extremely sorry. I didn't start that part yet. I am asking for help because, I have no idea how to load multiple value field in ArrayList.

Comment: @J.Chomel : thanks for your comment. but I am not trying to show multiple line in textView. I want to add multiple field in a ArrayList. Plz, see the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **ListView with a Custom Adapter.**

From what I can see (correct me if I am mistaken), you want the following :

1 - A ListView contains **entries** (rows in the list)

2 - You want to make these rows instances of a specific **CustomView** that contains, for example the **Airplanes**, **Airport**, etc

3 - You want an **EditText** that allows the user to specifically search for a given String

[Check this example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

Basically, explains on how you can achieve what you really need

1 - The ListView that uses a custom adapter.

2 - The CustomView of your liking (with all the elements you need : images, textviews, etc).

3 - The EditText that changes the list content whenever you write a string (of the data you want to search),

Comment: I try this out before but couldn't make is workable :(

Comment: Hi, Sohanoor. I've found a example that seems to suit your needs. Its a basic example but you can extend it from the on : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: @Sohanoor, I have editted the answer

Comment: I am exactly looking  this kind of solution. Thanks for your understanding. Now, I have to check the answer. Thanks again... @Ricardo

Comment: Good to know! If the solutions indeed suits you, dont forget to upvote and mark as the correct answer so that others in the future may be helped too. Kind regards!

Comment: This answer completely solve my problem. Thanks. @Ricardo –